# How to get no of copies during print in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

Am working on the flex application with print option.

I need to check the print count

my sample code is

```
var objPrintJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
var image:Image = new Image();
image.source = "assets/1.png";

if(objPrintJob.start() == true)
{
      objPrintJob.addPage(Sprite(image), null, options);
      objPrintJob.send();
      printCount++;
}
```

I attained the print count but unfortunately I can't get the

no of copies during print. When the user increases the no of

copies i need increment the PrintCount. please help how to get

the no of copies during print in flex

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way of knowing that since it's a completely different process.  Plus, I don't see what's the point of knowing the print count...

Comment: @J_A_X to restrict the print after some counts of print taken.

Comment: Wouldn't that be annoying? As in, maybe the user *wants* to print that many?  Either way, you have no control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it's just not possible AFAIK (and likely not possible with *any* web tech?)